# Übersetzung von "just a random guy"

Tags: single-word-request

Wie kann man z. B. den folgenden Satz treffend übersetzen?

> He was just a random guy.

Das Einzige, was mir dazu einfällt, ist

> Er war bloß irgendein Kerl.

Gibt es bessere Vorschläge?

Comment: Dein Vorschlag ist gut.

Comment: Die Übersetzung ist gut, ich würde wahrscheinlich nur zu "irgend *so* ein Kerl" greifen.

Comment: Eventuell passt auch *irgendjemand/irgendwer/irgendeiner*, je nach Kontext

Comment: "Ein x-beliebiger Typ."

Comment: @KilianFoth - der ist gut!

Comment: Abhängig vom Kontext und wenn es etwas freier sein darf, "irdend ein dahergelaufener (Kerl)", allerdings mit leicht negativer Konnotation.

Comment: To all those great comments: [answer] :)

Comment: Otto Normalverbraucher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er war nur ein x-beliebiger Typ, passt je nach Kontext am besten.